# Equivalence du mot "cynical"

Tags: traduction

Définition de Larousse de [cynique](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cynique/21363):

> Qui avoue avec insolence, et en la considérant comme naturelle, une
>   conduite contraire aux conventions sociales, aux règles morales.

Par contre je cherche la traduction du mot anglais [cynical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cynical):

> 1. believing that people are motivated purely by self-interest; distrustful of human sincerity or integrity.
> 2. based on or reflecting a belief that human conduct is motivated
>      primarily by self-interest

Quelqu'un peut m'aider ? Merci.

Comment: Je trouve que "cynique", dans son sens actuel, correspond bien à "cynical" pour ses 2 définitions (voir https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynisme_(contemporain) )

Answer (score 4):

Je dirais [égoïste](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9go%C3%AFste/28036):

> Qui fait preuve d'égoïsme, est caractérisé par l'égoïsme.

de [égoïsme](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9go%C3%AFsme/28035):

> Attachement excessif porté à soi-même et à ses intérêts, au mépris des
>   intérêts des autres.

Comment: merci. Pouvez-vous m'aider encore pour l'autre sens que je viens d'ajouter, svp ? "believing that people are motivated purely by self-interest; distrustful of human sincerity or integrity."